# Web Mapping Client with front-end query function

Tags: web-mapping, open-source-gis, web-service, qgis-web-client, arcgis-explorer

I'm searching for a cloud based Web Map Client that offers a front-end query tool so that my client can query against the data and visualize the results on the web map.  I'm trying to keep costs down and looking at Open Source and lower tiered subscriptions. I have no experience with development and coding. Research so far:

- Mango Map - query tool available for Professional tier
- CartoDB - SQL query on back end, not sure if it's available on the front-end
- MapGuide - has a query tool, but uncertain how to setup a server to host it

ArcGIS Explorer Desktop is a wonderful solution and an excellent example of what I'm trying to achieve, but the client is running a Mac OS and therefore cannot use the application without a Business account.

Comment: [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) + CartoDB in tandem might suit your purposes, as QGIS has a [CartoDB Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QgisCartoDB/) that could jump that client-side gap.

Answer (score 1):

At MangoMap we offer various query tools out of the box (no coding required). The most powerful is probably the Summary tool, there's a video here showing how it works:

[Summary Tool](http://docs.mangomap.com/knowledge_base/topics/summary-tool)

The MangoMap query tool is also another alternative:

[Query Tool](http://docs.mangomap.com/knowledge_base/topics/query-tool)